# Регулярные выражение деление строки по пробелу

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Нужно разделить на слова, пытался использовать `\s`, но  делит строку только на 2 слова, а остальные вызывают исключение `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
    String[] ln = com.split("\\s");
    Command = ln[0];
    try {
        Attribute1 = ln[1];
    }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exc){


    }

    try {
        Attribute2 = ln[3];
    }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exc){

    }

    try {
        Attribute3 = ln[4];
    }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exc){


    }
```

Comment: Добавьте код, как пытаетесь сделать это

Comment: А в чем ошибка то? Может и пробел всего один в строке?

Comment: пробелов, то как раз  хватает

Comment: Приложите к вопросу исходную строку и код вывода массива с результатами.

Answer (score 1):

В классе `String` есть специальный метод `split(String regex)`, который позволяет делить строку на части, используя переданные разделители в качестве регулярного выражения.

В случае с разделением по пробелам все просто:

```
String[] words = yourStr.split(" "); //words - массив слов без пробелов
```

Comment: regexp как раз правильно выбран: `\s` позволяет по табуляции бить в дополнении к пробелам.

Comment: Я не спец по регуляркам ;)

Comment: поменял, добавил вывод готовых слов(вывод переменных, которые равные элементам в массиве) и последнее слово равно null

Answer (score -1):

решил проблему null получался из-за того, что я напутал с номерами элементов в массиве и и последний выходил за пределы и получался null, спасибо всем за помощь)